# Negate match for word in the beginning of string in RE2 syntax?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, re2

Let's say that I have following strings:

- mail to
- tel:+358123456
- http://www.google.fi
- mailto:foo@bar.fi
- hello world
- telephone
- elephant
- penny
- link
- owl

How can I find only strings that do not start with 'tel:', 'http://' and 'mailto:' in RE2 syntax?

I've tried following with following syntax, but it filters out all of them:

```
[^(https?://|tel:|mailto:)]
```

edit: RE2 syntax does not support negative lookbehind/lookahead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: try `[a-zA-Z\s]+` it excludes all strings with special characters

Comment: It can be done with too clumsy alternations.

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao This question is not a duplicate because RE2 does not support negative lookbehind

Answer (score -1):

There is no drop-in workaround for the lack of negative lookbehind on RE2 that I know of.

Why don't you match on strings that do start with those keywords instead? Then you can dismiss those.